# Vs2012 compiler error C2143 : missing ; before *

Tags: c++

With my luck it's probably something very obvious that's slipped past me, but I've been struggling with C2143 for quite a while and I'm stumped.

```
game.h(21): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
game.h(21): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Game.h

```
#ifndef GAME_H_
#define GAME_H_

#include <irrlicht.h>
using namespace irr;
using namespace irr::core;
using namespace irr::scene;
using namespace irr::video;
using namespace irr::io;
using namespace irr::gui;

#include <iostream>

#include "CInput.h"
#include "CAssets.h"
using namespace rtsirr;

IrrlichtDevice *device = 0;
IVideoDriver *driver = 0;
ISceneManager *manager = 0;
CAssets *assets = 0; // Line 21, error here

#endif
```

CAssets.h

```
#ifndef ASSETS_H_
#define ASSETS_H_

#include "Game.h"

namespace rtsirr {

class CAssets
{
public:
    CAssets();
    virtual ~CAssets();
    ITexture* getTexture(stringw name);
    IMesh* getMesh(stringw name);
    IAnimatedMesh* getAnimatedMesh(stringw name);

    void load();

private:
    map<stringw, ITexture *> *textures;
    map<stringw, IMesh *> *meshes;
    map<stringw, IAnimatedMesh *> *animatedMeshes;
};

}

#endif
```

It seems that CAssets isn't being recognized as a valid type, but I can't figure out why. What's causing the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Can I ask a somewhat related question? What are all those variable decls doing *in a **header file*** ?

Comment: @WhozCraig Good point! Changing them to _extern_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a *cyclic dependency* in your *includes*. `Game.h` includes `CAssets.h` which in turn includes `Game.h` before even getting to define `CAssets`. The result from the preprocessor would be different, depending on the order of includes.

From your sample code, it seems that `Game.h` doesn't really need to know much about `CAssets` other than that is a type. You could replace the inclusion of `CAssets.h` with a forward declaration:

```
class CAssets;
```

You can even provide a `CAssets_fwd.h` that does only that. Otherwise, you will need to break the *cyclic dependency* between those two headers.

Comment: Well, the goal is that anything that includes Game.h would have access to CAssets. Would this still be possible with your method? Also, do I need to provide the namespace there as well?

Comment: @Patrick Moriarty: No, it isn't. You should look for a way to make `CAssets` independent of `Game.h`. And yes, the namespace is part of the declaration, so of course should be there...